# Silverstripe 3 - Custom HtmlEditorConfig with SSLink

Tags: silverstripe

I need to modify the html editor and add the silverstripe link button.
I tried it with 'sslink' but this doesn't work and I can't figure out how to add this button.

That's my full code

```
$minimal = HtmlEditorConfig::get('minimal');

$minimal->setButtonsForLine(1, array());
$minimal->setButtonsForLine(2, array());
$minimal->setButtonsForLine(3, array());

$minimal->addButtonsToLine(1, array(
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'underline',
    'strikethrough',
    'separator',
    'justifyleft',
    'justifycenter',
    'justifyright',
    'justifyfull',
    'separator',
    'bullist',
    'numlist',
    'outdent',
    'indent',
    'hr',
    'separator',
    'charmap',
    'removeformat',
    'separator',
    'sslink',
    'unlink'
));

$minimal->setOptions(array('width' => '100%', 'priority' => 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am pretty sure you'll need the ss plugin too for `sslink` to work:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('minimal')->enablePlugins(array(
    'ssbuttons' => sprintf('../../../%s/tinymce_ssbuttons/editor_plugin_src.js', THIRDPARTY_DIR)
));
```

Best thing is to take example from how the `cms` config is setup. Look at the file `framework/admin/_config.php` this will have all you need to get stated properly.

Comment: thank you that worked well ans the admin/_config.php was a good tip.
Is there a way, that my custom config loads on the first time? at the moment I always need to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: I think the 'loading' issue might have something to do with the mode config, double check it is 'none' and see if it helps...